# Why I got an error i.e app.js file is not found?

Tags: javascript, html

Here , it is my folder structure:

```
 ReactCourse      // It is the root directory
    public        // public is the subfolder in ReactCourse
      index.html  // It is the html file where I linked the js file into html page
    app.js        // It is the app.js file
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body class="root">
    <h1>I am header</h1>
    <script src="../app.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> // Here is the script tag
</body>
</html>
```

// But unfortunately , I got an error i.e File not found at the  console.

// It works fine when I put app.js file into public folder

Comment: Your script tag has the directory name `/scripts/` in the path, but there is no such directory.

Comment: `<script src="../app.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Answer (score 1):

According to your file structure, your app.js file is not inside a scripts folder.

`<script src="---------> ../scripts/app.js  <--------" type="text/javascript" ></script> // Here is the script tag`

You should probably be using this path:

`<script src="../app.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> // Here is the script tag`

Comment: @Hemant - what exactly did you try earlier? What you are describing that you did and did not work does not make sense.